# Cannot save keras model

Tags: keras, model, save, artificial-intelligence

I followed the tensorflow beginner tutorial to train a model with csv data.
I am not able to save the model with save method.
I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Philipp\IdeaProjects\TensorTest\Tutorial.py", line 135, in <module>
    heartattack_model.save('C:/Users/Philipp/Desktop/BachelorThesis/heartattack_model.keras')
  File "C:\Users\Philipp\IdeaProjects\TensorTest\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Philipp\IdeaProjects\TensorTest\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\preprocessing\index_lookup.py", line 839, in save_assets
    if self.input_vocabulary:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Code looks like this:

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras import layers


# Make numpy values easier to read.
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

import tensorflow as tf

heartattack_train = pd.read_csv(
"C:/.../heart_attack_prediction_dataset_real.csv",
skiprows=1,
names=["Patient ID", "Age", "Sex", "Cholesterol", "Blood Pressure", "Heart Rate", "Diabetes",
       "Family History", "Smoking", "Obesity", "Alcohol Consumption", "Exercise Hours Per Week",    "Diet","Previous Heart Problems", "Medication Use", "Stress Level", "Sedentary Hours Per Day", "Income",
       "BMI", "Triglycerides", "Physical Activity Days Per Week", "Sleep Hours Per Day", "Country",
       "Continent", "Hemisphere", "Heart Attack Risk"])

head = heartattack_train.head()

### features
heartattack_features = heartattack_train.copy()

### label
heartattack_labels = heartattack_features.pop('Heart Attack Risk')

heartattack_features.pop('Patient ID')

### Create a symbolic input
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32)

### Perform a calculation using the input
result = 2*input + 1
calc = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=result)


### To build the preprocessing model, start by building a set of symbolic tf.keras
# Input objects, matching the names and data-types of the CSV columns.

inputs = {}

for name, column in heartattack_features.items():
    dtype = column.dtype
    if dtype == object:
        dtype = tf.string
    else:
        dtype = tf.float32

    inputs[name] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=name, dtype=dtype)

### The first step in your preprocessing
# logic is to concatenate the numeric inputs together, and run them through a normalization layer

numeric_inputs = {name:input for name,input in inputs.items()
                  if input.dtype==tf.float32}

x = layers.Concatenate()(list(numeric_inputs.values()))
norm = layers.Normalization()
norm.adapt(np.array(heartattack_train[numeric_inputs.keys()]))
all_numeric_inputs = norm(x)


### Collect all the symbolic preprocessing results, to concatenate them later
preprocessed_inputs = [all_numeric_inputs]


### Strings to Integer
for name, input in inputs.items():
    if input.dtype == tf.float32:
        continue

    lookup = layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=np.unique(heartattack_features[name]))
    one_hot = layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=lookup.vocabulary_size())

    x = lookup(input)
    x = one_hot(x)
    preprocessed_inputs.append(x)


### concatenate all the preprocessed inputs together and build a model that handles the preprocessing
preprocessed_inputs_cat = layers.Concatenate()(preprocessed_inputs)

heartattack_preprocessing = tf.keras.Model(inputs, preprocessed_inputs_cat)

### plot overview concatenation
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model = heartattack_preprocessing , rankdir="LR", dpi=72,\
                      to_file='C:/Users/Philipp/Desktop/BachelorThesis/plot.png', show_shapes=True)


### This model just contains the input preprocessing. You can run it to see what it does to your data.
# Keras models don't automatically convert pandas DataFrames because it's not clear if it should be
# converted to one tensor or to a dictionary of tensors. So, convert it to a dictionary of tensors:
heartattack_features_dict = {name: np.array(value)
                     for name, value in heartattack_features.items()}


### Slice out the first training example and pass it to this preprocessing model,
# you see the numeric features and string one-hots all concatenated together:
features_dict = {name:values[:1] for name, values in heartattack_features_dict.items()}
heartattack_preprocessing(features_dict)


### Now, build the model on top of this
def heartattack_model(preprocessing_head, inputs):
    body = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(64),
        layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    preprocessed_inputs = preprocessing_head(inputs)
    result = body(preprocessed_inputs)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, result)

    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
    return model

heartattack_model = heartattack_model(heartattack_preprocessing, inputs)

### train the model
heartattack_model.fit(x=heartattack_features_dict, y=heartattack_labels, epochs=10)

### save the model
heartattack_model.save('C:/Users/...')
```

---

The las line of code is where the error occurs.
I do appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

I tried chatgpt and searching in stackoverflow but could not resolve the issue